# Machine check error on ASUS while booting from USB

Tags: asus

I put the last Ubuntu iso on my USB stick using UNetBootin, after formatting it to fat32. I've already done that before with other operating systems and it worked. I can't actually boot Ubuntu from USB since I get a black screen with the error "Machine check error" on top the an automatic reboot happens. The error appears right after the boot, I can't see anything else before.

I'm using my ASUS X54L latop. Does anybody know how to solve this?
Installation from CD/DVD works.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in my ZenBook :

- booting on a live debian
- trying to boot on the installed system (didn't work, for another reason)
- retry to boot on the live system => MACHINE CHECK ERROR and no boot.

I tried to boot another live usb key (with grub, not with syslinux) and it worked

Then I retried to boot my live debian system again => it worked

So it just seemed that the machine check error is coming from the fact that your machine is in a wrong state internally, and booting on something else triggered a reset somewhere ... (like in some pci state or ...)

clearly an Asus bug IMHO...